# HSK form machine readability

Tags: hsk

I understand this is not strictly related to Chinese Language but may be helpful for people taking the [HSK](http://www.chinesetest.cn/gosign.do?lid=0).

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LNoa.jpg) is what the test form looks like. The first part contains the personal info. The second part the answers to the test. Additionally, you will have a booklet with the questions (and that you will have to return). You will need to have a pencil to mark the right boxes.

The form will be read and evaluated by a machine. What is the most appropriate way to mark the boxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using 4B pencil, mark the whole box with solid black. (For me, 2B is not dark enough and 4B+ is too soft, green 中华牌铅笔 is the best.)

Sharp your pencil with a knife (don't use pencil sharpener) and make sure the pencil top can cover the whole box with a single stroke, this can save your time.

Prepare 2 or more pencil for the test and protect your pencil top, also prepare a good eraser.

Print out or buy sample answer sheet and do some practice.

Normally this sheet will give to you before the real test paper, immediately mark your personal information at this stage will save some time and double check your information is correct.

[Here is a Chinese Version Guide](http://jingyan.baidu.com/album/4d58d5411d1ddf9dd4e9c0e3.html?stepindex=1&st=5&net_type=&bd_page_type=1&os=1&rst=&word=%E6%8B%9B%E8%A1%8C%E5%8D%A1)

Answer (score 0):

The rules on the admission ticket I received stipulate using a 2B pencil.